# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer'

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

In my studies I had a problem with the flyway, I started the project according to the video lesson, but after starting I noticed that the versions of flyway and spring were out of date and put another version in the pom.xml Drope the created category table and the version e scheme flyway shows me this error when I try to upload the project.

```
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: 
> 
> Migration checksum mismatch for migration version 01
> -> Applied to database : 1894708545
> -> Resolved locally    : -2070596035
```

Pom.xml before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.algaworks.algamoney-api</groupId>
    <artifactId>algamoney-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>algamoney-api</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Pom.xml after:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
<!--        <packaging>jar</packaging> -->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.algaworks.algamoney-api</groupId>
    <artifactId>algamoney-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>algamoney-api</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</proje
```

ct>

Myscript:

```
CREATE table categoria(
    id BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Lazer');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Alimentação');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Supermercado');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Farmácia');
INSERT INTO categoria (nome) values ('Outros');
```

There is no table in the database yet created and no record in schema_version because I also dropped it. Why the error? Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My pom:

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <!-- <packaging>jar</packaging> -->
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.algaworks.algamoney-api</groupId>
    <artifactId>algamoney-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>algamoney-api</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the release documentation of Flyway, it says, that from Flyway 4 to 5/6 the schema_version table has changed to flyway_schema_history.

Also the algorithm to calculate checksum has changed:

**version 3** -

crc32 over bytes:

```
bytes = resource.loadAsBytes()
...
crc32.update(bytes);
```

**version 5** (not a verbatim copy) -
crc32 over lines (ignoring CR/LF, and using UTF-8 encoding):

```
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(resource.loadAsString(configuration.getEncoding())));
[...]
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
     crc32.update(line.getBytes("UTF-8"));
 }
```

The class name which flyway uses for checksum calculation in v6 is **org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.ChecksumCalculator**

The first change (about table) can be tackled by using the following property:

```
  flyway.table=schema_version
```

The second change( checksum algorithm) can be tackled by using **flyway repair** before calling migrate (either through commandline or through code)

```
Flyway flyway = fluentConfig.schemas(schemaName).load();
flyway.repair();
flyway.migrate();
```

Comment: but the problem was that the spring and flyway versions were incompatible. tks

Comment: @Mussum why incompatible? I am using the same versions in my project.. what are the compatible versions that fixed your issue?

Comment: @Abhinada check my answer.